# openstack instance can not access internet

Tags: openstack

An instance created in the OpenStack can not access the internet. I have created an instance from the ubuntu cloud image.

In the security groups, I allowed all the ports for ingress and egress request of ICMP, TCP and UDP. I can ssh the instance and ping the floating IP of the instance and all the other instances on the private network but I can not ping any other IP address outside the network. In the network topology, the router is connecting the public and private network but the instance can not access the internet and i can not ping 8.8.8.8.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Presumably the "other" IP addresses for the instance are on the private network.  If so, you can't access them, except from other IPs on the private network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. I was able to resolve this issue by allowing ICMP ingress requests because of port 22 in the security groups.

Comment: *"by allowing ICMP ingress requests"* - yes, but *"because of port 22 in the security groups"* doesn't make sense.  Ping uses ICMP (by default), but port 22 (SSH) is for the TCP address family and not relevant to ping.

Answer (score 0):

check you ml2 and linuxbridge or ovs agent. this is because of miss-configuration. presumably type-driver and mechanism-driver mismatch, or provider network is not set correctly.
please post your config here, so we can find the problem.